# Trying to find the integral of a function using u subs.

Tags: calculus

I need help integrating this one.
$\int \frac{\sin(50x)}{1+\cos^2(50x)}\,dx$

I started with $u = 50x$ as my $u$-sub

$$\int \frac{\sin(u)}{1+\cos^2(u)}\,dx$$

Comment: Wha is a u sub ?

Comment: You need a $1/50$ in front of your integral.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
\int\dfrac{\sin u}{1+\cos^{2}u}du&=-\int\dfrac{1}{1+\cos^{2}u}d(\cos u)=-\tan^{-1}(\cos u)+C.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int \frac{\sin(50x)}{1+\cos^2(50x)}dx&=\frac1{50}\int \frac{\sin(u)}{1+\cos^2(u)}du\\
&=-\frac1{50}\int \frac{(\cos(u))'}{1+\cos^2(u)}du\\
&=-\frac1{50}\arctan(\cos(u))+C\\
&=-\frac1{50}\arctan(\cos(50x))+C\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}